# What is the difference between physical and magical lifesteal?

Tags: smite

Lifesteal items allow you to heal yourself by attacking another player.  However, I am finding items are either physical lifesteal or magical lifesteal.

I know gods are classed as either physical or magical, but not sure how this applies to these two types of lifesteal.  Maybe there is no connection.

It looks like physical lifesteal applies to auto attacks only, and magical applies to abilities.  However, this is only from my observations.  I cannot say for certain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Physical lifesteal applies only to physical basic attacks and abilities, which specifically say, they apply on-hit effects; magical to magical basic attacks and abilities. A physical god deals physical damage on basics, a magical god magical. This is so, because physcial basics are more powerful than magical, i.e. they scale better with physical power.

You can buy magical lifesteal on a physical god and vice versa, but it will not have any effect.

From the [Smite Wiki](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Statistics#Lifesteal_-_Physical_and_Magical)

> Physical Lifesteal only works when dealing damage with basic attacks. Magical Lifesteal works with the damage dealt by both abilities and basic attacks, but AoE abilities have a diminished Lifesteal effect. Physical Lifesteal caps at 100 while Magical Lifesteal caps at 65.

other sources:
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Smite/comments/2f8qo5/pysical_magical_life_steal_vs_magical_life_steal/)
[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/smitetraining/comments/2ajo72/does_magicalphysical_lifesteal_work_on_abilities/)

Comment: You should also note that there are physical abilities that will proc "on hit" effects such as lifesteal.

Comment: Does this mean that magical lifesteal items are only available to magical gods (and physical lifesteal for physical gods)?

Comment: No, you can of course buy magical lifesteal on a physical god and physical lifesteal on a magical god, it just doesn't do anything whatsoever.

Comment: Ouch.  Seems like a design flaw, right?  Well, unless the item has other properties beyond lifesteal.

Comment: *No, you can of course buy magical lifesteal on a physical god and physical lifesteal on a magical god, it just doesn't do anything whatsoever.* - this is my confusion.  Could you add this info to the answer, or alternatively how magical lifesteal is only applicable if you are a magical god (etc)?

Comment: Did do. Though is their even an item or god, where there is any reason for confusion? Only soul eater appears to be somewhat interesting to a magical god, who needs attack speed. All others also have their corresponding power.

Comment: The confusion is in knowing that some items don't give lifesteal if, for example, you select a magical lifesteal item but you are a physical god.  This was my confusion.

Comment: Yeah, but there is literally no reason to ever buy magical lifesteal as a physical god. All magical lifesteal items also have magical power, which is also useless to a physical god. Soul Eater is literally the only lifesteal item, which doesn't have it's corresponding power value. So unless, there is a god who is physical, but has abilities, which scale with magical power or vice versa, there is no reason to ever consider the items with the wrong lifesteal.